# Trying to get rid of Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, boot, partitioning, debian

So I had a system that dual booted with windows 7 and ubuntu.  I wanted to get rid of ubuntu and install debian.  So I got the iso and went through the install.  When I got to the part where I partition my HDD I told it to erase the part with ubuntu and to then use it to install debian.  It said it did that.  I finished and had my debian install up and running.  I have the grub that allows me to choose between debian and windows.  When I went to boot into windows the boot loader there still gave me the option to boot into ubuntu.  I thought that was weird since debian said it wiped that part of the disk.  I booted into ubuntu and found that it was on the same partition as debian.  I could access all the debian files.  Yet it had it mounted as if it were a separate disk.

What happened?  Am I totally wrong in thinking that the installation should have formatted the partition before putting debian onto it?  How can two distros run on the same partition?  Also, when I checked the disk space with df -h I found that even though ubuntu and debian were on the same partition they reported different amounts of new and used space (same total space)??  I'm bewildered and I don't know what to do now.  I just want ubuntu to go away.  What do ya think?

Thank you,
Bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you wiped was everything but the partition where you installed Ubuntu since... you installed Ubuntu using Wubi. The only way to remove it is going to the Program Files, All Programs and look for Wubi/Ubuntu, then hit uninstall.

Comment: I didn't use wubi.  Maybe i should've...

Comment: Actually... I totally did use wubi.  Boy do I feel silly.  You da man Braiam!